# Semantic segmentation labeling

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I'm trynna make a scratch code of Semantic segmentation through U-Net. I'll use Cityscapes Dataset. I'm trying to make a dictionary(python) composed of the key(car, train, human, etc) and the value(rgb info). How can I match the dictionary with my ground_truth data?

example of labeling dictionary is like below

```
color_map = {
'0': [0, 0, 0],             # unlabelled
'1': [128, 64, 128],        # road
'2': [244, 35, 232],        # sidewalk
'3': [70, 70, 70],          # building
'4': [102, 102, 156],       # wall
'5': [190, 153, 153],       # fence
'6': [153, 153, 153],       # pole
'7': [250,170, 30],         # traffic_light
'8': [220, 220, 0],         # traffic_sign
'9': [107, 142, 35],        # vegetation
'10': [152, 251, 152],      # terrain
'11': [0, 130, 180],        # sky
'12': [220, 20, 60],        # person
'13': [255, 0, 0],          # rider
'14': [0, 0, 142],          # car
'15': [0, 0, 70],           # truck
'16': [0, 60, 100],         # bus
'17': [0, 80, 100],         # train
'18': [0, 0, 230],          # motorcycle
'19': [119, 11, 32]         # bicycle
}
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far? And what do you mean by *"match the dictionary with my ground_truth data"*?

Comment: you should read the "label" image not as RGB, but as **indexed** RGB. this should give you the labels directly.